# Cars in my city are expensive or The cars in my city are expensive(with the)? the question is a little longer, so it is below

Tags: articles

Cars in my city are expensive or The cars in my city are expensive(with the)? When I write in my language on google translate. it says that: Cars in my city are expensive(without the), but if I write something different for example: Cars in my city are large, google translate translates "The cars in my city are large", so it adds article the now. Is google translate bad? Isn't the correct one normally with the? Or I'm wrong?

Answer (score 2):

An automatic system like Google Translate doesn't necessarily pick up on all the nuances of every language.

It's fine to say *Cars in my city are expensive,* which refers to cars in general (all the car dealerships in the city charge high prices). It wouldn't be wrong to use *the*, but we are more likely to use the definite article when referring to a particular set of cars such as *all the cars parked in my street.*

Comment: if i understood correct, the variant with THE is correct too but the one without the is better for general use? Thanks for your help

Comment: @AndreiAlex General ideas in English take the plural or the: Apples are good for you. AND The apple is good for the health.